# How to get the the account holder details from Indian UID (Aadhaar) Number in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to get the the account holder details from Indian UID (Aadhaar) Number in .net

Answer (score 0):

To access that UID API you need to contact UDI Team.

> Authentication User Agency (AUA) and Sub-AUA

An organization or an entity using Aadhaar authentication as part of its applications to provide services to Aadhaar holders. Examples   include   Government Departments,   Banks, and other   public   or   private organizations.  All AUAs (Authentication  User  Agencies) must  be  registered  with in Aadhaar authentication server to perform secure authentication.Sub-AUA is an an entity having a business relationship with AUA offering specific services in a particular domain.

> For latest documents related to Aadhaar authentication, partner
>   guidelines, other APIs, and related documents, see 
>   http://authportal.uidai.gov.in